# PLSQL : Go back to the start of the file after writing

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to write inside a file at the start of it everytime. I guess it is something with utl_file.fseek but I dont know how to use it exactely.

```
Loop
   utl_file.put(my_file, '12345678');
   utl_file.fflush(my_file);
   -- go back to the start to rewrite on the 8 digits number
end loop;
```

ty

Comment: What have you tried? The docs indicate you can provide either an absolute or a relative offset. Choose one and omit the other and see what happens. It sounds like you can either provide an absolute offset of `0` or a negative relative offset equal to or greater than your current position. Per the docs both should reset the pointer to the beginning.

Comment: There is an oracle error whatever I do...I am wondering if we can use fseek when the file is opened in write mode... That would be inconvenient if we cannot.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I can't think of a reason why you would want to overwrite bytes you've already written in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i researched the internet **FSEEK** can be used only in **READ** mode.

You can follow these approches.

1.You can insert it into a table with serial number and then write to the file the first descending serial number or insert only the last 8 digit number.

2.You can write it to a file from start to end and then read the file from end and write to a file.